# What is the duration of native actionbar.show() and hide() animation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to do some animation when the actionbar is animating. However, I don't know the duration of actionbar animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, **the native actionbar animating time seems to be hard-coded in the [Android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl.doHide%28boolean%29)** after version 4.1 (with no attributes, no dimensions, no methods) and it's set to **250ms**:

Example of the implementaiton of `actionbar.hide()` method in Android 4.1/4.4:

```
public void doHide(boolean fromSystem) {
    if (mCurrentShowAnim != null) {
        mCurrentShowAnim.end();
    }

    if (mCurWindowVisibility == View.VISIBLE && (mShowHideAnimationEnabled
            || fromSystem)) {
        mContainerView.setAlpha(1);
        mContainerView.setTransitioning(true);
        AnimatorSet anim = new AnimatorSet();
        float endingY = -mContainerView.getHeight();
        if (fromSystem) {
            int topLeft[] = {0, 0};
            mContainerView.getLocationInWindow(topLeft);
            endingY -= topLeft[1];
        }
        ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContainerView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, endingY);
        a.addUpdateListener(mUpdateListener);
        AnimatorSet.Builder b = anim.play(a);
        if (mContentAnimations && mContentView != null) {
            b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, View.TRANSLATION_Y,
                    0, endingY));
        }
        if (mSplitView != null && mSplitView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mSplitView.setAlpha(1);
            b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSplitView, View.TRANSLATION_Y,
                    mSplitView.getHeight()));
        }
        anim.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(mContext,
                com.android.internal.R.interpolator.accelerate_cubic));
        anim.setDuration(250);
        anim.addListener(mHideListener);
        mCurrentShowAnim = anim;
        anim.start();
    } else {
        mHideListener.onAnimationEnd(null);
```

This happens also on [Lollipop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/core/java/com/android/internal/app/WindowDecorActionBar.java#815):

```
public void doHide(boolean fromSystem) {
        if (mCurrentShowAnim != null) {
            mCurrentShowAnim.end();
        }
        if (mCurWindowVisibility == View.VISIBLE && (mShowHideAnimationEnabled
                || fromSystem)) {
            mContainerView.setAlpha(1);
            mContainerView.setTransitioning(true);
            AnimatorSet anim = new AnimatorSet();
            float endingY = -mContainerView.getHeight();
            if (fromSystem) {
                int topLeft[] = {0, 0};
                mContainerView.getLocationInWindow(topLeft);
                endingY -= topLeft[1];
            }
            ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContainerView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, endingY);
            a.addUpdateListener(mUpdateListener);
            AnimatorSet.Builder b = anim.play(a);
            if (mContentAnimations && mContentView != null) {
                b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, View.TRANSLATION_Y,
                        0, endingY));
            }
            if (mSplitView != null && mSplitView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mSplitView.setAlpha(1);
                b.with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSplitView, View.TRANSLATION_Y,
                        mSplitView.getHeight()));
            }
            anim.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(mContext,
                    com.android.internal.R.interpolator.accelerate_cubic));
            anim.setDuration(250);
            anim.addListener(mHideListener);
            mCurrentShowAnim = anim;
            anim.start();
        } else {
            mHideListener.onAnimationEnd(null);
        }
    }
```

Before 4.1 (e.g. [4.0.1)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl.hide%28%29) there's no hardcoded duration value (actually there's no value at all), anyway you could use reflection to access the `Animator`'s duration after the first animation. The field to access is the following:

```
private Animator mCurrentShowAnim;
```

I know that this is not a complete answer, but I think it might be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

At least in 4.3, it was 250ms.

See the source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl.doShow%28boolean%29)

Comment: Do you believe?  Or is this actually the case?  Please rewrite your answer in a more concrete way.  As it stands, this answer looks like a comment.

Answer (score -3):

eh @vincentzhou your question is not well structured but i thing this can give you some guide on how to set the time you want you to manipulate you element in JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#action').show();
      setTimeout(function() { 
       $('#action').fadeOut(); 
     }, 5000);
   });
```

this will display the element with `id="action"` for 5s. hope it can help

Comment: I am sorry but I think I am asking a question about android.

Answer (score -3):

ActionBar.Show - Shows the ActionBar if it is not currently showing. There is no duration attached to that. It makes the ActionBar visible until a actionBar.Hide is called.

Hope this clarifies

Comment: I know. But when you call actionbar.show(), the actionbar will show with an animation.

Comment: I mean the duration of that animation.